# Laravel filter a value in all columns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
public function getBooks($input)
{
    $books= Book::where('book_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%')->get();
    return Response::json($books);
}
```

I know how to filter a column by a given value. But how do I filter ALL columns by a given value. For example, I have a column called 'category' where user should be able to use the same search bar to filter the category.

Something like:

```
$books = Book::where('all_columns', 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%')->get();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most databases do not support searching all columns simultaneously. I'm afraid you'll likely have to chain all of the columns together:

```
$books = Book::where('book_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%')
    ->orWhere('another_column', 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%')
    // etc
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 17):

You have to add a `where` clause for each column like @JoelHinz suggests. To simplify things a bit you can use an array and a loop:

```
$query = Book::query();
$columns = ['book_name', 'foo', 'bar'];
foreach($columns as $column){
    $query->orWhere($column, 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%');
}
$books = $query->get();
```

Or even use the schema builder to retrieve all column names from your table:

```
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing('books');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this override function to apply condition to all rows.

```
public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true) {
        return parent::newQuery()
            ->where('another_column', 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%');
    }
```

Now Book Model will provide only result who match your requirement.