# Search in all columns (Eloquent)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am doing a method to search in all the columns of the table

```
$busqueda = $request->input('buscar');

/* Get columns */
$client = new Crmclient;
$table = $client->getTable();
$columns = \Schema::getColumnListing($table);


foreach ($columns as $column) {
     $users_client = Crmclient::where('user_id', Auth::id())
           ->where($column, 'like', '%' . $busqueda . '%')
           ->orWhere('user_id_subaccount', Auth::id())
           ->where($column, 'like', '%' . $busqueda . '%')
           ->get();
                        
}
```

whats wrong? I can get all the columns and if I do var_dump inside the loop in some interactions it looks for me and in others not, but finally I get the empty array

Comment: why double: ->where($column, 'like', '%' . $busqueda . '%') ?

Comment: It works the same as a conditional. `if ($var1 && $var2 || $var1 && $var3)`

Comment: Can you implement full text searching? It is way too easy to search columns using full text indexes. here's the [reference](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php#:~:text=Full%2DText%20Search%20in%20MySQL,based%20columns%20in%20the%20table.), hope it helps

Comment: I think you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543166/laravel-filter-a-value-in-all-columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$columns = \Schema::getColumnListing((new Crmclient)->getTable());

$users_client = Crmclient::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', Auth::id())->orWhere('user_id_subaccount', Auth::id());
})->where(function ($query) use ($columns, $busqueda) {
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        $query->orWhere($column, 'like', "%{$busqueda}%");
    }
})->get();
```