# Search in all columns in a eloquent model

Tags: laravel

After following some SO questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543166/laravel-filter-a-value-in-all-columns), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125793/multiple-column-with-same-search-string-in-laravel) ,[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089966/how-to-get-search-query-from-multiple-columns-in-database)) I was able to create the following code:

```php
$search = 'Project 1';
$columns = ['id', 'name', 'key'];

$projects = Project::where('tenant_id', 1)->select($columns);

foreach ($columns as $column) {
    $projects = $projects->orWhere($column, 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
}
dd($projects->get());
```

However the code above returns ALL results in a model instead of only returns that match the `$search` variable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you do `dd($projects->toSql());` (instead of `->get()`) you can see the base SQL being executed. You likely have a scoping issue, `WHERE ... OR ... OR ...` instead of `WHERE ... AND (WHERE ... OR ... OR ...)`

Comment: @TimLewis Yes, i had noticed that before this question, but couldn't find any way to fix the scope of eloquent queries. How can I do that?

Comment: That's actually quite easy, but admittedly hard to find in the documentation. I'll add a quick answer for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a scoping issue, and you'll need a nested `where()` clause to handle this:

```
$search = 'Project 1';
$columns = ['id', 'name', 'key'];

$projects = Project::where('tenant_id', 1)
->where(function ($subQuery) use ($columns, $search){ 
  foreach ($columns as $column) {
    $subQuery = $subQuery->orWhere($column, 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
  }
  return $subQuery;
})->select($columns)->get();
```

Note: The initial `->where()` can be adjusted to `->orWhere()` if that better fits your needs.

Using `->where|orWhere(function(){ ... })` allows you to scope the where logic to avoid collisions/ambiguity with other conditions.